# How to create a DSL Connection in network-manager in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: internet, dsl

In 17.04 I could create DSL Connections in the network settings. In 17.10 the option is not available anymore. How can I create a DSL connection?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a DSL connection using command line interface to network manager.

**Solution:**

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name "My DSL"` it will drop you into an interactive prompt.
3. `set pppoe.username ISPUsername` (obviously you should replace `ISPUsername` with the username given by your ISP)
4. `save`
5. `quit`
6. Now you are be able to edit other configuration in `Settings` > `Network` and it will now look like this:

[image: Wired Connection]

8. After pressing [image: gear icon] you will be able to edit the connection :)

[image: connection edit]

for further configuration. See [this answer for an example session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268285/59928).

As to the graphical interface lacking the option: most likely some packaging issue. I highly recommend [to report a bug to launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/). As I am unsure what would be the correct package, it is my considered opinion you choose network manager. (If there's a better place, maintainers will figure out who to reassign to.)

Comment: I wasn't able to save without giving the username. I needed to use
`set pppoe.username [username]` then `save` and at last `quit`. you can add these commands in you answer so that it becomes easier for the readers to find what to do.

Comment: An edit and a **+1**!

Comment: Hi-Angel, thanks, man, you saved my day. It works for 18.04 too.

Answer (score 4):

The UI options for PPPoE and thus DSL connections were removed from the “standard” network connection configuration panel of GNOME.

To access the full range of options formerly available use the *Network Connections*  application (`nm-connection-editor`) and refer to [How do I set up a PPPoE connection?](/a/89713/175814)

Comment: IMO, this ought to be the accepted answer - it's far easier than the currently accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the terminal to run the command `sudo pppoeconf`.