# How to create autoconnect wired PPPoE connection?

Tags: network-manager, internet, 17.10, pppoe, dsl

I was able to create a DSL connection from network manager in Ubuntu 17.04. It used to connect automatically whenever cable was connected. But in Ubuntu 17.10, I cannot create a DSL connection through network manager. So, I have to create connection using `sudo pppoeconf`. But it does not auto connects.

**My question is:** Is it possible to make `pppoeconf` autoconnect whenever the wire is connected?

Comment: Why can't you create a DSL connection in network manager?

Comment: @Hi-Angel In Ubuntu 17.10, while creating a connection, there is no option to select dsl connection.

Comment: This is weird, I can't even google up such an issue. Well. Have you upgraded 17.04 → 17.10? I mean, in that case you should still have the connection you've used previously, check if you see it in the output of `nmcli con show`. Otherwise, check if the command `nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name "My DSL"` works.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Cool Your second command works! Now I can edit the connection in network manager and that connects automatically like ubuntu 17.04. For your first question: I completely removed ubuntu 17.04 and then installed 17.10. So the connection was removed. BTW You can answer my [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966647/how-to-create-a-dsl-connection-in-ubuntu-17-10) question and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation, I wasn't able to create DSL connection in network-manager in ubuntu 17.10. So, I used pppoeconf and it doesn't connect automatically. But Hi-Angel's comment solved my problem and Now I am able to create a DSL connection in network-manager and it connects automatically.

[Hi-Angel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966647/how-to-create-a-dsl-connection-in-ubuntu-17-10-in-network-manager?noredirect=1#comment1570644_966647)