# Why does not 18.04 LTS have any DSL option?

Tags: networking, network-manager, 18.04, pppoe

Why has the option of adding a DSL connection on the tab for Wired Connection been removed after 17.04?

I was using 16.04, and then upgraded to 17.04 and later 17.10, I still had the DSL connection, as it was saved from previous versions.

However, on a fresh install of 17.04, 17.10 or 18.04, I cannot create DSL connections anymore. In my opinion this is a important feature, as many Indian ISPs with many customers still use DSL.

For an average user who has a single device it's easier to create a DSL connection, and put the DSL modem in bridge mode, to avoid hassle of port forwarding.

Comment: See (https://askubuntu.com/questions/966647/how-to-create-a-dsl-connection-in-network-manager-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Although at first it seems to create a new Wired connection My DSL. Editing the connection to save the authentication password deleted the connection and I couldn't see it anymore. The instructions and the screenshots doesnot apply to 18.04