# Can't find wired connection option on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: internet, pppoe, dsl

Current network setting page:

[image: VPN not set up, Network Proxy off]

I use pppoe connection and have recently switched to Ubuntu, I am having a hard time setting up the pppoe connection. Isn't there suppose to be a **Wired +** on the top right?

Wireless works perfectly.

```
    $ sudo lshw -c network 

  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       logical name: enp2s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 80:ee:73:dd:70:49
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df114000-df114fff memory:df110000-df113fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 81
       serial: 0c:54:15:5d:c6:77
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 memory:df000000-df001fff
```

---

```
$ dkms status
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Is the ethernet cable connected, and also connected to a switch/hub/router/modem? Is there a blinking LED light next to the ethernet connection on your (desktop) computer? Edit your question (and use the {} code formatting option) and show me the output of **sudo lshw -c network** and **dkms status**. Report back to @heynnema.

Comment: @heynnema edited. and on etc/NetworkManager.conf it says etc/NetworkManager does not exist

Comment: I didn't ask about NetworkManager.conf, but it's located in **/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**. You didn't answer my questions about your ethernet wiring. Edit your question with **lsmod | grep -i r81** and **ls -al /etc/modprobe.d** and **more /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf** and **more /etc/network/interfaces** and report back to @heynnema.

Comment: Your wired network connection seems fine. Did you try to [create a DSL connection](/a/1072407/175814) (as in my answer to the linked question)? Did it work? If not, what went wrong or counter to your expectations? Were there any error messages? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nmcli dev show`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to install the [pppoe](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/pppoe) package first, then you need to run some commands via CLI to make it work.

Basically, you have to create a new entry on NetworkManager with the `nmcli` utility.

See the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966647/how-to-create-a-dsl-connection-in-network-manager-in-ubuntu-17-10) for the procedure (it's for 17.04 but should work on 18.04 too).

Comment: pppoe pack is installed and i have tried the tutorial you linked above but there is still no wired option

Comment: @AyonAzad you can also try directly from the cli with `sudo pppoeconf`

Comment: i did that too... still cant find the entry i made with it on the network section