# How to fix/setup DSL wired connection in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, was using a wired connection without problem (this connection does not require username/password), but yesterday I tried to setup a wired connection with another ISP and couldn't set it up.

I followed the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966647/how-to-create-a-dsl-connection-in-network-manager-in-ubuntu-17-10?rq=1) but it didn't connect.

When I click on the name of the ISP, a pop up screen came up showing me the username and password and lower below Cancel / Connect, when I click on connect, Ubuntu takes few seconds trying the came back with the same screen, it seems the connection was refused.

The cable is OK because I have a dual boot and in Win8.1 worked just fine.

I'm not knowledgeable with Ubuntu, so if you can give me step by step instructions on how to solve it, it's much appreciated.

Please note that I have to switch between Win8.1/Ubuntu so the feedback may take some time to get posted.

PS: the article also mentioned using `pon dsl-provider`, I tried that command from terminal, but got this error: no dsl-provider file under /etc/ppp/ (I'm not sure about the path), so why the file is not there? How can I create one? Thanks.

Comment: By `pon dsl-provider` I think it meant for you to substitute your new IPSs name.

Comment: @waltinator, It did not work, I tried that command with "dsl-provider" and "ADSL Taipei" and got this error: The file /etc/ppp/peers/ADSL Taipei does not exist. Please create it or use
a command line argument to use another file in the /etc/ppp/peers/ directory.

Comment: @waltinator, I found a sample of the file on the net, the sample is as follows: <br/>noipdefault
<br/>defaultroute
<br/>replacedefaultroute
<br/>hide-password
<br/>noauth
<br/>persist
<br/>plugin rp-pppoe.so eth0
<br/>user "joe.user"
<br/>usepeerdns<br/>and changed the user with my username, but got this error: eth0 unrecognized. What am I missing?